# C++ memcpy Access violation big chunk of memory

Tags: c++

I am new in c++ area.
On line `memcpy(combined + 14 + 40, pThirdPart, size);` it's throws

> Exception thrown at 0x0FB046EE (vcruntime140d.dll) in Memcpy.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00544000.

Why it's happening?

```
const long size = 8294400;
char firstPart[14] = "3412345";
char secondPart[40] = "daffda";
char *thirdPart = new char[size];

sprintf_s(thirdPart, size, "Test TEst tset ... and other symbols");

BYTE *pFirstPart = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&firstPart);
BYTE *pSecondPart = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&secondPart);
BYTE *pThirdPart = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&thirdPart);

BYTE *combined = new BYTE[(size + 14 + 40)];

memcpy(combined, pFirstPart, 14);
memcpy(combined + 14, pSecondPart, 40);
memcpy(combined + 14 + 40, pThirdPart, size);
```

Comment: Obligatory question: Why aren't you just using `std::string`?

Comment: What is `BYTE`?

Comment: Going out on a limb I'd guess that `reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&thirdPart);` should be `reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(thirdPart);` - though I'm honestly not sure what the point of all these `reinterpret_cast`s is

Comment: @nvoigt [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types): typedef unsigned char BYTE;

Comment: [std::byte](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) is a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pThirdPart` points to the address of `thirdPart`, not the address pointed to by `*thirdPart`.

You are probably confused because the address of an array is not the same as the address of a pointer. When you have an array like so

```
char array[10];
```

taking the address of this variable is the same as just referencing  it without and index. `array` is the same value as `&array`.

But with a pointer the situation is different

```
char *pointer;
```

`pointer` is not the same value as `&pointer`

This is just a quirk of C/C++ that you have to be aware of.

So in your program you should have

```
BYTE *pFirstPart = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&firstPart);
BYTE *pSecondPart = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&secondPart);
BYTE *pThirdPart = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(thirdPart);
```

or even

```
BYTE *pFirstPart = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(firstPart);
BYTE *pSecondPart = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(secondPart);
BYTE *pThirdPart = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(thirdPart);
```

both variants will work.